# div and background image?

Tags: css, html, background-image

im having a problem regarding using background property with url('location') value with a div element. All browsers do not show the background image for any content written within the div tag.

code:

HTML:
body has a div tag with the class = slide. this div tag contains some content and links.

CSS:
`div.slide { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(images/btnslide.gif);
}`

please help me identify the error. maybe i have misused div tag. please point out the solution for the above problem

thanks in advance

Comment: Does the image exist under that path? Are you 100% sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either haven't set the height for your `.slide` element, or you haven't cleared the floats for the elements inside `.slide`. Try setting a height or adding `overflow: auto` if you want to clear the floats inside your `<div>`.

Comment: Also, consider checking the path for your image - the images are chosen relative to the directory the CSS is in.

Comment: thanks wex.. problem was that css and images were in different directory and path i had written were relative to html file present in the main directory

Comment: Sure thing. Please accept this solution if you feel like it's helped you solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This code should work by default, as everybody said something else is wrong.

Either the height is wrong or the image does not exist.

Which browsers are failing exactly?

If you like you can try writting the CSS with full syntax:
`background: url(..) top left repeat;`